# How to restore latest AdventureWorks database in psotgresql using pgadmin4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have downloaded the backup file from Microsoft website for AdventureWorks database which has an extension of `.bak`.

Now I want to restore it in my postgresql 16.2 using pgadmin4 8.2 version.

While restoring I am getting below error. It seems that we cannot restore `.bak` file and that we need only .tar file.

Is there any way where I can restore the database and practice SQL queries ?

I tried restoring it with there GUI but was not able to do so.

Error while restoring

[Error Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgG1i.png) :

> pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Comment: Hi - Why do you think you can restore a backup of a SQL Server database into a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: **AdventureWorks** is a **SQL Server** sample database by Microsoft - you **CANNOT** restore a SQL Server database onto Postgres ...

Comment: bak files are for MS SQL Server and fot for postgres.